# The code compiles it does not read staff.txt

Tags: c++, private, getter, setter

The code compiles it does not read staff.txt. Not sure how to fix in the code. the error must be in reading the staff.txt of the code. Does anyone have an idea? output is in the image provided. Background on the question:

You are tasked to create 2 ADTs: customers and staff. Each customer will have a first and last name, an indication if the customer is enrolled in the “preferred” program, the car they are driving, and the amount of money owed to the company. On the other hand, each staff member will have a first and last name, the car they are driving, and their salary. In a real-world problem, there would obviously be more records associated with each staff member and customer.

ODU rentals would like you to automatically process txt files and print the information to the console screen. When you perform this process, ensure that your member variables are private. In addition, be sure to use getter and setter functions to manipulate and print your data. You may print your data in any format as long as it is organized. An example of correct output can be seen below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Customer {

string fname;
string lname;
int enroll;
string car;
float amount;
public:

//Defining the customer ADT
Customer();
void setFirstName(string fnm);

void setLastName(string lnm);
void setEnroll(int e);

void setCarName(string cnm);
void setAmount(float amt);
string getFirstName();
string getLastName();
int getEnroll();
string getCarName();
float getAmount();

void printData();
};

Customer::Customer() {
fname = lname = car = "";
enroll = 0;
amount = 0;
}
void Customer::setFirstName(string fnm) {
fname = fnm;
}
void Customer::setLastName(string lnm) {
lname = lnm;
}
void Customer::setEnroll(int e) {
enroll = e;
}
void Customer::setCarName(string cnm) {
car = cnm;
}
void Customer::setAmount(float amt) {
amount = amt;
}
string Customer::getFirstName() {
return(fname);
}
string Customer::getLastName() {
return(lname);
}
int Customer::getEnroll() {
return(enroll);
}
string Customer::getCarName() {
return(car);
}
float Customer::getAmount() {
return(amount);
}
void Customer:: printData() {

cout << left << setw(25) << getFirstName()+" "+getLastName() << left <<setw(15) << getEnroll();

cout << left << setw(15) << getCarName() << left << setw(15) << fixed << setprecision(2) << getAmount() << endl;

}

class Staff {
string fname;
string lname;
string car;
float salary;
public:

//Defining staff ADT
Staff();
void setFirstName(string fnm);
void setLastName(string lnm);
void setCarName(string cnm);
void setSalary(float sal);
string getFirstName();
string getLastName();
string getCarName();
float getSalary();

void printData();
};

Staff::Staff() {
fname = lname = car = "";
salary = 0;
}
void Staff::setFirstName(string fnm) {
fname = fnm;
}
void Staff:: setLastName(string lnm) {
lname = lnm;
}
void Staff::setCarName(string cnm) {
car = cnm;
}
void Staff::setSalary(float sal) {
salary = sal;
}
string Staff::getFirstName() {
return(fname);
}
string Staff::getLastName() {
return(lname);
}
string Staff::getCarName() {
return(car);
}
float Staff::getSalary() {
return(salary);
}
void Staff:: printData() {

cout << left << setw(25) << getFirstName()+" "+getLastName() << left << setw(15);
cout << getCarName() << left << setw(15) << fixed << setprecision(2) << getSalary() <<endl;

}

//Main function
//Read txt files
int main() {

string fnm, lnm, carnm;
float amt, sal;
int e, i=0, recno;

ifstream fstaff("staff.txt");
if(!fstaff) {
cout << "File can not be opened" << endl;
exit(1);
}

fstaff >> recno;
Staff s[recno];

cout << left<<setw(25) << "Name" << left << setw(15) << "Car" << left << setw(15) << "Salary" <<endl;
cout << "____________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

for(i=0; i<recno; i++) {
fstaff>>fnm>>lnm>>carnm>>sal;
s[i].setFirstName(fnm);
s[i].setLastName(lnm);
s[i].setCarName(carnm);
s[i].setSalary(sal);
s[i].printData();
}
fstaff.close();

ifstream fcust("customers.txt");
if(!fcust) {
cout << "File can not be opened"<<endl;
exit(1);
}

fcust >> recno;
Customer c[recno];

cout << endl << endl;
cout << left << setw(25) << "Name" << left << setw(15) << "Preferred" << left << setw(15) << "Car" << left << setw(15) << "Bill" << endl;
cout <<"____________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;

for(i=0; i<recno; i++) {
fcust >> fnm >> lnm >> e >> carnm >>amt;
c[i].setFirstName(fnm);
c[i].setLastName(lnm);
c[i].setEnroll(e);
c[i].setCarName(carnm);
c[i].setAmount(amt);
c[i].printData();
}
fcust.close();
return 1;
}
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ30o.png)

Comment: Please.. Do not paste images of text. Copy the text and paste it into the question as text. The console does allows it.

Comment: Did you checked the path relative to executable? 
For testing purpose you can try absolute path and then figure out the relative path.

Comment: This is just a massive code dump. Please [edit] to remove the portions of the code that are not directly related to your question. Your code should be in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the problem - make not of the word *minimal*. It should be the absolute fewest lines of code that it takes to reproduce the issue, and not a single line more.

Comment: Also, what happens when you step through the code in a debugger? It's the absolute best way to find an error in your code logic. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. You'll never have a better tool available to you as a programmer, and it's never too early to start.

Comment: Like others said, make a smaller example. If you suspect the code does not read the file,  and you do not know how to use the debugger, comment out everything else, or make a new file with just the lines that try to read from the file. See if that works. If it does not, post your new ( and much smaller ) question here, and I'm sure you will quickly get answers on  how to solve it.